# Apply function per group of values of a key in list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's suppose I have this:

```
my_list = [{'id':'1','value':'1'},
{'id':'1','value':'8'},
{'id':'2','value':'2'},
{'id':'2','value':'3'},
{'id':'2','value':'5'},
]
```

and I want to apply a function (eg `shuffle`) for each group of values separately for the key `id`.

So I would like to have this for example:

```
my_list = [{'id':'1','value':'1'},
{'id':'1','value':'8'},
{'id':'2','value':'3'},
{'id':'2','value':'5'},
{'id':'2','value':'2'},
]
```

Therefore I do not want something to change between the different groups of values (eg `id`=1,2 etc) but only within each one separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` directly in case your list is sorted by `'id'` or sort by `'id'` and use `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import random

my_list = [{'id':'1','value':'1'},
           {'id':'1','value':'8'},
           {'id':'2','value':'2'},
           {'id':'2','value':'3'},
           {'id':'2','value':'5'}]

res = []
for k, g in groupby(my_list, lambda x: x['id']):
    lst = list(g)
    random.shuffle(lst)
    res += lst

print(res)
# [{'id':'1','value':'1'},
#  {'id':'1','value':'8'},
#  {'id':'2','value':'3'},
#  {'id':'2','value':'5'},
#  {'id':'2','value':'2'}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `res += lst` instead of append to keep the result as a flat list?

Comment: when I run it I get two nested lists

Comment: @schwartz721, Oops. My bad; just corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that `groupby` works only if the list was sorted before. If it wasn't, then it won't work.