# List of dicts - Partial shuffle

Tags: python-3.x, shuffle

Let's suppose I have this:

```
my_list = [{'id':'2','value':'4'},
{'id':'6','value':'3'},
{'id':'4','value':'5'},
{'id':'9','value':'10'},
{'id':'0','value':'9'}]
```

and I want to shuffle the list but I want to do it partly - by this I mean that I do not want to shuffle all the elements but only a percentage of them (eg 40%).

For example like this:

```
my_list = [{'id':'4','value':'5'},
{'id':'6','value':'3'},
{'id':'2','value':'4'},
{'id':'9','value':'10'},
{'id':'0','value':'9'}]
```

How can this be efficiently done?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Also, the example you show shuffles 3 elements - wouldn't that be 60%?

Comment: @rassar, I think that I shuffle 2 numbers to start with but the percentage does not matter anyway - it will be a variable. (I am currently building the code - I may use a list of random numbers for the positions and then swap the relevant numbers).

Comment: Ok! Once the code's built, let us know if you have any difficulties with it.

Comment: This seems related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847407/apply-function-per-group-of-values-of-a-key-in-list-of-dicts). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` does not allow you to specify only part of a list, it will always shuffle an entire list.

A trade-off between effort, speed, and memory footprint would be to slice out the part of the list you want to shuffle, do it, and then assign it back to that slice:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> y = x[:5]
>>> shuffle(y)
>>> x[:5] = y
>>> x
[2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Cool but in this way you introduce a bias in your lists by only shuffling the last n (eg 5) elements.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit You can do this with numpy easily. `my_array = np.asarray(my_list); idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(my_array.size), size=2, replace=False); my_array[sorted(idx)] = my_array[idx]`

Comment: @user2653663, I guess that you can see that if `np.random.choice` come up with an already sorted list for `idx` (eg [0 1]) then nothing will change in the array because `idx` and `sorted(idx)` will be the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Yes, there's a chance of shuffling a sorted list in the same order as the original list, else it wouldn't be random. If you want pseudo-random shuffling that makes sure that none of the indices are left at it's original position, then you can just implement such an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following:

```
from random import sample

shuffle_percentage = 0.4
x = sample(range(len(my_list)), int(len(my_list) * shuffle_percentage))

for index in range(0, len(x)-1, 2):
    my_list[x[index]], my_list[x[index+1]] = my_list[x[index+1]], my_list[x[index]]
```